# Using the same CArchive object for archive and un-archive

Tags: visual-c++, serialization, reusability

Following is a sample code:

```
CFile serFile;
serFile.Open(_T("Person.ser"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);

CArchive writer(&serFile, CArchive::store);

me.Serialize(writer);

writer.Close();
serFile.Close();

serFile.Open(_T("Person.ser"), CFile::modeRead);

CArchive reader(&serFile, CArchive::load);
CPerson clone;
clone.Serialize(reader);

reader.Close();
serFile.Close();
```

Here, I have a `writer` which archives the object `me`. Then, I use another `CArchive` object `reader` to un-archive it. Is it possible to re-construct or set any property of `writer` to make it, the reader instead of declaring another `CArchive` object `reader`?

Thanks.

Comment: DId you check if you could edit this property CArchive::load);  after creation of reader. I mean after the object is created dont you have a settype or setattribute some function that would let you change it.

Comment: `CArchive::load` is an `enum` which we use while constructing a `CArchive` object. `enum Mode { store = 0, load = 1, bNoFlushOnDelete = 2, bNoByteSwap = 4 };`

Answer (score 0):

I guess a CArchive *cReadAndWrite pointer
can be used and you can delete it and reuse it. But i am not sure on this feasibility.